# match multiple columns within the same row

Tags: excel

**Table 1**. I have a table that looks like this:

```
X       Y       Z
1       a       p
2       a       p
6       b       p
7       c       p
9       c       p
```

**Table 2**. I have a different table that looks like this:

```
        Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4   
Row1            p       p       p
Row2            a       b       c
Row3    1               
Row4    2               
Row5    3           
Row6    4           
Row7    5           
Row8    6                   
Row9    7                       
Row10   8           
Row11   9
```

I want to mark "TRUE" when rows of table 1 match with values of its column in Table 1. As a result for example:

```
        Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Row1            p       p       p
Row2            a       b       c
Row3    1       TRUE        
Row4    2       TRUE        
Row5    3           
Row6    4           
Row7    5           
Row8    6               TRUE        
Row9    7                       TRUE    
Row10   8           
Row11   9                       TRUE
```

Here is what I have tried so far. This is the formula for Col2 Row3:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(AND(MATCH(Col1Row3,X:X,0), MATCH(Col2Row1,Z:Z,0)), MATCH(Col2Row2,Y:Y,0)), "TRUE", ""),"")
```

I think it's not working because I am not containing the matches within the same row. How can I achieve my result?

Also, I do not want to specify a specific row in the formula because I have thousands of rows in Table 1, and Table 2 has to select values among those thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($F:$F,$A3,$G:$G,B$2,$H:$H,B$1),TRUE,"")
```

[image]

Comment: One more question: How do I give you ten stars?